# Observable Collection not updating datagrid upon linq

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a datagrid and textbox in my application. I will provide a number in textbox and upon clicking the button I want the datagrid to get the data from the given number. The datagrid's Itemsource is a ObservableCollection. The problem is datagrid not updating When i click the button.

I'm learning wpf.  I have a datagrid which is a ObservableCollection. The data for the datagrid is populated via the sql query. The Binding to datagrid works fine. I searched online and found that with linq we can search the collection and get the data but the datagrid doesn't reflect any changes.

```
ModelClasstab.Where(d => d.claimnumber == "123456712");
```

In the above I have hardcoded the textbox data to check whether the condition works

Window.xaml

```
<Label Width="69" Height="23.277" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,-10,30,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="From Date"/>
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="113" Height="19.277"  Margin="-200,1,-228.962,0"  x:Name="txtboxComments"/>
<Button  Command="{Binding dataSearch}" Margin="300,-20,30,0" Width="60" Height="23.277"  Content="Search"></Button>
<DataGrid x:Name="datagrid" ItemsSource="{Binding ModelClasstab}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="False" Height="350" Width="365" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

ViewModel.cs :

```
   public class ViewModel
  {
    public RelayCommand dataSearch { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<tabpageAuditInformationModel> ModelClasstab {get; set;} 


    public ViewModel()
  {   
    FillList();
    dataSearch = new RelayCommand(o => Search());
  }

 public void Search()
    { 
     ModelClasstab.Where(d => d.claimnumber == "123456712");
    }


public void FillList()
    {
        string connectionString = "Data Source=192.168.6.102; Initial Catalog=Operations Productivity Tool;Integrated Security=SSPI;";

        string sql = "SELECT distinct Date_Audited as Date , claimNumber as 
 claimnumber,Audit_id,[Start Time],[End Time],[Total Time] as 
 [Total_time_taken(Mins)] , [Final Status] as finalstatus " +
" FROM dbo.[opcod Audit Information]" +
            //or date = dateadd(day,-1,cast(getdate() as date))) " +"where userName = 'rengar2' ";

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
            {

                try
                {


                    adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                    ds = new DataSet();
                    adapter.Fill(ds, "tblCountries");

                    if (ModelClasstab == null)
                        ModelClasstab = new ObservableCollection<tabpageAuditInformationModel>();

                    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        var month = Convert.ToDateTime(dr[0]).Month;
                        var year = Convert.ToDateTime(dr[0]).Year;
                        var day = Convert.ToDateTime(dr[0]).Day;


                        ModelClasstab.Add(new tabpageAuditInformationModel
                        {
                            claimnumber = dr[1].ToString(),
                            Date = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", month, day, year),
                            Starttime = dr[3].ToString(),
                            EndTime = dr[4].ToString(),
                            TotalTime = dr[5].ToString()
                        });


                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
     }
```

Model.Cs

```
 public class tabpageAuditInformationModel
  {
   public String Date
   { get; set; }


   public String claimnumber
   { get; set; }

   public String Starttime
   { get; set; }

   public String EndTime
   { get; set; }

   public String TotalTime
   { get; set; }

}
```

Edit : After reading the comments, I assigned the value to  a variable and remove all the items in the collection and add only the selected data into the list. Here i cant able to run two foreach at the same time. The breakpoint is not going into the second forloop at all. I'm not sure about my approach. Let me know if there is any better approach.

```
         var d1 = ModelClasstab.Where(d => d.claimnumber == "123456712");
                    foreach (var a1 in ModelClasstab.ToList())
                        ModelClasstab.Remove(a1);
                    foreach (var a in d1.ToList())
                        ModelClasstab.Add(new tabpageAuditInformationModel
                        {
                            claimnumber = a.claimnumber,
                            Date = a.Date,
                            Starttime = a.Starttime,
                            EndTime = a.EndTime,
                            TotalTime = a.TotalTime
                        });

                }
```

Comment: Calling `ModelClasstab.Where(d => d.claimnumber == "123456712")` doesn't modify the contents of the collection. `.Where` is an extension method that returns a brand new `IEnumerable<tabpageAuditInformationModel>`. You have to assign that to something. Or you just modify the collection manually.

Comment: @Enigmativity I understood the issue. As you said I have assigned the value into a variable. I thought of removing all the items in the collection and added the new data into the collection. But I'm facing difficulty on adding the new data after removing the irem.

Comment: No, I'm saying you haven't assigned the value to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

With `Collection.Where` clause you don't modify the collection, so you don't see any changes in the `DataGrid`.
One of the many possibilities is to hold your DB data in some variable and set in `Search` the `ModelClasstab` property:

```
public void Search()
{
    ModelClasstab=new ObservableCollection<tabpageAuditInformationModel>(DbData.Where(d => d.claimnumber == "123456712"));
}
```

For such a way `ModelClasstab` don't need to be an `ObervableCollection` and (!) your ViewModel has to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.